# ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Asking a question in stackoverflow for the first time.
My ionic2 app has got an issue. I can get json in console ald, but when I want it show in my apps, news.html got some problem.

**providers/news-data.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class NewsDataProvider {
    data:any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  getUsers() {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
          console.log('success');
        });
    });
  }

}
```

**news.ts**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-news',
  templateUrl: 'news.html',
})
export class NewsPage {
    users:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public newsData:NewsDataProvider){
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
      this.newsData.getUsers().then(data => {
        this.users = data;
      });
  }

}
```

**news.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="danger" no-border-bottom>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="ios-contact"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title></ion-title>

  </ion-navbar>

  <ion-toolbar no-border-top>
    <ion-searchbar color="danger"
                   [(ngModel)]="queryText"
                   (ionInput)="updateSchedule()"
                   placeholder="Search">
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
    {{user.title}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

**console show**

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.
>       at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.es5.js:1689)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10790)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12216)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12155)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12858)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:12799)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (NewsPage.html:22)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12784)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12122)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12485)

**but can get data in Network there ald**

Comment: U click the URL will show u what I got in Network there. But I got nothing in apps there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you are using `object` on `ngFor` but `ngFor` only support iterables such as `Array`.

I test from the `url` you provided and find out that you should retrieve from `res.json().data` which is an **array**(should be the data you want to be used at `ngFor`). refer the below change.

```
this.http.get('http://bravonet.my/ct3/api/news?api_key=123').map(res => res.json().data).subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  resolve(this.data);
  console.log('success');
});
```

and **[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/swd8wGA04mbgy4vFeQU4?p=preview)**(*don't confirm this with Chrome because it blocks http request by default when using https*).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! This problem waste me one day ald..zzz
But still dun know why just add '.data' at that place

Comment: 看了资料才知道自己人 哈哈哈 
加下微信吧 大神 交流一下

Comment: @YuyangHe 大神算不上   略有研究。

Answer (score 0):

you are already subscribing to the http request in the function. no need to create a promise again and return. Just return the http request from the `news-data.ts` and subscribe to it from `news.ts` file

```
getUsers() {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return this.http.get('http://bravonet.my/ct3/api/news?api_key=123').map(res => res.json())
}
```

now catch it like this

```
  getUsers() {
      this.newsData.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data; 
    });
  }
```

Comment: news.ts file  subscribe got problem said 'property 'subcribe' does not exit on type promise<any>....'

Comment: should be `subscribe` not `subcribe`

Comment: wrong type.. I wrote subscribe, but still this error

Comment: make sure to use `json` filter to render objects in DOM  `{{item | json}}`